# While loop with if condition in a dataframe

Tags: while-loop

I have a dataframe where one of the columns (cylinders) include numeric data ranging from 3-8. Using a while loop in R, i need to create a new vector called 4_cyl that contains the names of the rows that have exactly 4 cylinders with an if command inside the loop to check for 4 cylinders

Comment: What tool is that where you want to have such dataframe?

Comment: First read the [tour] and [ask]. Next pick a programming language. Then come back with a [mcve].

Comment: looking for a solution in R